# Cookie splitting precision for traffic routing in Google App Engine (Flexible environment)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

According to the official App Engine's [Traffic Splitting docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/splitting-traffic), it seems possible to achieve a 0.1% precision for traffic routing:

> Using cookies to split traffic makes it easier to accurately assign
>   users to versions. The precision for traffic routing can reach as
>   close as 0.1% to the target split.

However, the UI seems to only allow 1% (see image below).

Are the docs wrong, or am I missing something?

[image: Traffic Splitting seems to only allow a 1% precision]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to interpret precision as the resolution of the target value. It's actually the difference between the target value and the actual value(s) you get.

So for a 1% target value a 0.1% precision means you could get actual values between 0.9% and 1.1%.

But technically the statement doesn't really say very much - it's not a guarantee, so it leaves room for pretty much any precision ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot! As you say, I got confused with resolution :)